# flask jquery to stop refresh

Tags: jquery, flask, forms

I am able to implement this tutorial here: https://pythonprogramming.net/jquery-flask-tutorial/

However, I want to expand on it and use the input from the html as a variable to do other code with it. I am unable to grab the variable like i've done in the past with:

```
lang =request.form['proglang']
```

and reference it like this to display on the html template:

```
<h3>You responded with: {{ lang }} </h3>
```

Please let me know how to get the variable from the html input in my

```
@app.route('/interactive', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Full code html template:

```
{% block body %}
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/background_process', {
              proglang: $('input[name="proglang"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
              $("#result").text(data.result);

            });
            return false;
          });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='container'>
    <h3>Welcome! Which is the best programming language of them all?</h3>
        <form>
            <input type=text size=5 name=proglang>
            <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
        </form>
    <p id=result></p>
    </div>



</body>


    <body>
    <div class='container'>
    <h3>You responded with: {{ lang }} </h3>
    </div>
    </body>

{% endblock %}
```

Full code flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/interactive', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def interactive():
    try:
        lang =request.form['proglang']
    except:
        lang = '1234'


return render_template('interactive_v2.html', lang=lang)

@app.route('/background_process')
def background_process():
    try:
        lang = request.args.get('proglang', 0, type=str)
        if lang.lower() == 'python':
            return jsonify(result=lang)
        else:
            return jsonify(result='Try again.')

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference variables from flask using jinja when you use ajax ($.getJSON in your case). When you make an ajax call, you are sending a request to `background_process` and it returns a json response. This response cannot be rendered with Jinja (curly brackets) and can only be used with javascript code.

`{{lang}}` gets rendered only once when `interactive` is loaded. When you get a response from ajax, you get it in a json format and you have to use jquery to manipulate or use the data and not jinja's curly brackets

Lastly, you cannot have more than one `<body>` tag in an html document.

Here is how to achieve what you want and a corrected format of your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/background_process', {
              proglang: $('input[name="proglang"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
              $("#result").text(data.result);
              // ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE
              $("#lang").text(data.result);


            });
            return false;
          });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <h3>Welcome! Which is the best programming language of them all?</h3>
        <form>
            <input type=text size=5 name=proglang>
            <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
        </form>
        <p id=result></p>
    </div>

    <div class='container'>
        <h3>You responded with: <span id="lang">{{lang}}</span> </h3>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```